# Method to download using generics asks for more context

Tags: swift, generics, nsurlsession

I wrote a method using generics in order to make it reusable to any kind of download. It downloads json arrays and returns a generic object or an error.
This is my class to download json arrays from server:

```
import Foundation
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}
class LTLNetworkClient: NSObject {

    fileprivate var session : URLSession
    fileprivate var objectTask : URLSessionDataTask?

    override init() {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
        self.session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)
    }

    /**
    Download asynchronously json object from Server and returns it into generic data models
    */
    func getData<K: Codable>(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<[K]>) -> Void) {
        let sessionDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
            if let jsonData = responseData {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let response = try decoder.decode([K].self, from: jsonData)
                    let result: Result<[K]> = Result.success(response)
                    completion(result)
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            } else if let error = responseError {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "Cannot form jsonData with Response Data", code: 501, userInfo: nil)
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        sessionDataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the method and the error I get:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to fix it and why this error appears?
Many thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your method declaration:

> ```
> func getData<K: Codable>(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<[K]>) -> Void)
> ```

This method has a type parameter, `K`, which is only used in the type of the `completion` argument. When the compiler sees a call to `getData`, it has to deduce a concrete type for `K` based on the argument type of the closure you pass as `completion`.

And here's your call:

> ```
> networkClient.getData(request: urlRequest) { (result) in
>     // Do stuff
> }
> ```

In this call, the `completion` closure is `{ (result) in }`. What is the type of `result`? There is no information given about it, so all the compiler knows is that `result` must be type `Result<[K]>` for some type `K`. It has no way to deduce a concrete type for `K`, so it emits an error.

You can make the type explicit like this:

```
networkClient.getData(request: urlRequest) { (_ result: Result<[SomeConcreteCodableType]>) -> Void in
    // Do stuff
}
```

where `SomeConcreteCodableType` is some concrete type that conforms to `Codable`. The `Codable` conformance is required because of the constraint in `getData`'s declaration.

A different solution is to change `getData` to take another argument that lets the caller specify `K` directly:

```
func getArray<K: Codable>(of: K.Type, for request: URLRequest,
    completion: @escaping (Result<[K]>) -> Void) {
    ...
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
networkClient.getArray(of: SomeConcreteCodableType.self, for: request) { result in
    // Do stuff
}
```